# Best way to benchmark spark reading time

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-2.0

What is the best way to benchmark the reading time of spark ?

```
    val rdd = spark.sparkContext.binaryFiles(s"$Path//$partitionColumn=$partitionId/*.avro")
implicit val streamEncoder: Encoder[(String, PortableDataStream)] = Encoders.kryo[(String, PortableDataStream)]
spark.createDataset(rdd)
```

I use spark 2.2

Comment: I use a simple implementation ([see on scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/hBR2LayLSn2FYqFlvEqRgA)). you can use it like this: `timeTrack { spark.createDataset(rdd) }`. not sure if it is suitable for you.

Comment: How do i trigger an action to make spark reading my files ?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use this library: https://github.com/LucaCanali/sparkMeasure.

Check examples available in the Readme file. Like [this Databrick notebook](https://databricks-prod-cloudfront.cloud.databricks.com/public/4027ec902e239c93eaaa8714f173bcfc/2061385495597958/2729765977711377/442806354506758/latest.html).

For instance you could read your Avro using the `runAndMeasure` function:

```scala
taskMetrics.runAndMeasure(spark.createDataset(rdd).count())
```